# How can I get an AudioBufferSourceNode's current time?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

When working with audio elements (`<audio>`) or contexts(`AudioContext`), you can check their `currentTime` property to know exactly the play time of your buffer.

All of this is fine an dandy until I created multiple sources (or `AudioBufferSourceNode`) in a single `AudioContext`.

The sources could be played at different times, therefore I would need to know their corresponding `currentTime`'s, to illustrate:

[image: an audio context connected to it's sources with unknown play times.]

Some base code for you to work off:

```
buffer1 = [0,1,0]; //not real buffers
buffer2 = [1,0,1];

ctx = new AudioContext();

source1 = ctx.createBufferSourceNode();
source1.buffer = buffer1;
source1.connect(ctx.destination);
source1.start(0);

source2 = ctx.createBufferSourceNode();
source2.buffer = buffer2;
source2.connect(ctx.destination);
setTimeout(1000/*some time later*/){
    source2.start(0);
}

setTimeout(1500/*some more time later*/){
    getCurrentTime();
}

function getCurrentTime(){
    /* magic */
    /* more magic */
    console.log("the sources currentTime values are obviously 1500 (source1) and 500 (source2).");
}
```

Comment: Subtract the start time from the current time.

Comment: @KingMob take into consideration the play/pause behaviour :)

Comment: Subtract the start time from the current time, and add to the elapsed time. ;-)

Comment: @KingMob hahaha, yeah i get it, but maybe there is smth classier and less grindy.

Comment: How do you pause an [AudioBufferSourceNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode) anyway? Web Audio is pretty low-level.

Comment: You use the `.stop()` method and then create another source (as they can just be used once)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What I usually do is create a wrapper for the audio source node that keeps track of the playback state. I've tried to minimise the code below to show the basics.

The core idea is to keep track of the time the sound is started and the time the sound is 'paused' and use those values to get the current time and to resume playback from the paused position.

I put a [working example on codepen](http://codepen.io/ianmcgregor/pen/EjdJZZ)

```
function createSound(buffer, context) {
    var sourceNode = null,
        startedAt = 0,
        pausedAt = 0,
        playing = false;

    var play = function() {
        var offset = pausedAt;

        sourceNode = context.createBufferSource();
        sourceNode.connect(context.destination);
        sourceNode.buffer = buffer;
        sourceNode.start(0, offset);

        startedAt = context.currentTime - offset;
        pausedAt = 0;
        playing = true;
    };

    var pause = function() {
        var elapsed = context.currentTime - startedAt;
        stop();
        pausedAt = elapsed;
    };

    var stop = function() {
        if (sourceNode) {          
            sourceNode.disconnect();
            sourceNode.stop(0);
            sourceNode = null;
        }
        pausedAt = 0;
        startedAt = 0;
        playing = false;
    };

    var getPlaying = function() {
        return playing;
    };

    var getCurrentTime = function() {
        if(pausedAt) {
            return pausedAt;
        }
        if(startedAt) {
            return context.currentTime - startedAt;
        }
        return 0;
    };

    var getDuration = function() {
      return buffer.duration;
    };

    return {
        getCurrentTime: getCurrentTime,
        getDuration: getDuration,
        getPlaying: getPlaying,
        play: play,
        pause: pause,
        stop: stop
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks! I was planning doing this but had a few doubts :)

Comment: So this only work is you're always playing back at at the same `playbackRate`. There is an issue in the WebAudio spec to add a `playbackPosition` parameter to the AudioBuffer. https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/296

Comment: To solve problem with playbackRate just use 
`elapsed = (context.currentTime - startedAt) * sourceNode.playbackRate.value`

Comment: Why not use `suspend()` and `resume()` of the audio context instead of recreating the sourceNode every time?

Answer (score 0):

Old thread *(and very useful! thanks!)* , but maybe worth mentioning that in the [example above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31653217/12266390) instead of

```
function update() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
    info.innerHTML = sound.getCurrentTime().toFixed(1) + '/' + sound.getDuration().toFixed(1);
    }
update();
```

it may be more precise and less resource intensive to use a `createScriptProcessor`
like explained in [this post](https://apiko.com/blog/how-to-work-with-sound-java-script/)

```
const audioBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(response.data);
const chan = audioBuffer.numberOfChannels;
const  scriptNode = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(4096, chan, chan);
scriptNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
scriptNode.onaudioprocess = (e) => {

  // ---> audio loop <----

};
```

[Update]

Note: As of the August 29 2014 Web Audio API spec publication, this feature has been marked as deprecated, and was replaced by AudioWorklet (see AudioWorkletNode). https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/12/audio-worklet

Comment: Just stumbled over this while trying to get a simple "how many frames are left in my buffer" solution. I read this as implying the only "proper" way to do it is by using a custom AudioWorklet. Brief google research didn't yield anything that looked immediately usable, are you aware of something that could be fudged into doing the job?